# How to get short description under heading - Visual Composer

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, visual-editor

We are looking a Visual Composer Shortcode list. Please look at the image, how to put content below the heading just like "Text2" as similar to Custom Heading .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got resolution,

```
vc_map( array(
        "name" => __( "xxxxxx" ),
        "base" => "xxxxx",
        "icon" => plugins_url('img/vc-icon.png', __FILE__),
        'description' => __( 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx' ),
        "params" => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'dropdown',
                'heading' => __( 'Select xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx' ),
                'param_name' => 'id',
                'admin_label' => true,
                'value' => $xxxxcvx
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

I implemented `'admin_label' => true,` and then it's working fine....